# How to Display blob content (doc,ppt,xls) in an Angular web

Tags: angular, file, blob

Everyone, I'm trying to view file content on browser from the server which is sent in blob format. Displaying pdf (blob) is successful using [ng2-pdfjs-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer).

This plugin can view pdf in blob without any issue and without saving the file on user filesystem, but I also want to display other formats like ppt, doc, Xls, etc without storing or convert blob to user filesystem.

Is it possible to view the blob formatted office files on the browser without saving the file on the user machine?

I had tried other file viewer plugins available on `npm` but they do not render blob format.

The backend is in spring using solr search engine which returns the file blob object to the client end (angular).

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: we implemented by converting every document to pdf using apache poi and sending back the response to frontend in a blob and displayed the content using pdf viewer .you can use alternative open source libreoffice online and openoffice.

Answer (score 0):

we have to use different strategy by converting every document to pdf using apache poi and sending back the response to frontend in a blob and displayed the content using pdf viewer .you can use alternative open-source [LibreOffice](https://libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-online/) online and OpenOffice.